# Input a value in Dijit Combobox using the IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, combobox, dojo, webdriver, dijit.form

I am doing a webdriver automation of a webpage that uses Dijit webelements (they suck).

One of this elements is the infamous Dijit Comobobox:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html

The webdriver can input a value doing several steps (click here, sendkeys, click there, etc), but the testing is done in ie9 and this really slow.

I want to do it with a Javascript function, like:

```
document.getElementById("married_Status").setAttribute('value', 'Nicely_Married');
```

But this doesnt work. I can input text in the field, that it is not able to select one of the options.